# Rails ActiveJob for infinite loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, infinite-loop, rails-activejob

The application I am developing needs to have an infinite loop to handle business logic that is completely separate from user input (they would only view it).  Since this is a break from tradition MVC, I thought an Active Job would be a good place to put it.

The logic in the loop would poll microcontrollers on the same network.  I have little to no ability to change the code on these so I have to adapt to the unique protocol they are using. When the microcontrollers respond, the server will need to do some calculations and store those in the database.

The job would be launched when the server application is.  Only one instance of it should exist so I don't want to put it in my models or controllers.  I have tried launching it from a couple of places in the config folder but it would cause an initialized constant NameError.

What would be the correct way to launch a job when the server is initialized?  Is there another approach you would take?

I am a webdev newb using Ruby 2.2.0 and Rails 4.2.0.

Comment: Does the polling need to happen in continuous real time?

Answer (score 1):

How about using scheduled jobs? For example you could schedule it so that every minute a job is scheduled to run that will poll for whatever you need to be polling for?

Have a look at this Gem:

https://github.com/javan/whenever